# Unable to install wine => Depends: wine1.6-amd64

Tags: apt, wine

I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 18.4 but am completely failing. I have activated `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then try to install wine, with the below output. There are too many dependencies for me to install I believe.

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2)
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                              libglu1:i386
                     Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.9) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.9) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libncurses5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install via the software manager it says "Not available"

I do not have broken packages:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

[Edit] - Information from comments

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install -y --install-recommends winehq-stable=4.0.3~bionic \
> wine-stable=4.0.3~bionic wine-stable-amd64=4.0.3~bionic wine-stable-i386=4.0.3~bionic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpcap0.8:i386 (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libncurses6:i386 but it is not installable or
                                  libncurses5:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  libncurses:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libgnutls28:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libjpeg62-turbo:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libjpeg8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libpng16-16:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libpng12-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libsane1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libtiff5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you try to install `wine-stable`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks very much @karel. I have tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` this is empty.
Wine-stable is  wine-stable: `Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~xenial)`

Comment: Ah thank you @Terrance, interestingly this opens up a whole host of problems for me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @Terrance on clean VM with official repositories and Wine repository (OpenSuSe) I do not have any problems with [my method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205596/66509). So other PPAs from your system PPAs may cause problems.

Comment: @N0rbert I responded on the other.  It appears that if you have Wine already installed that the `libfaudio0-i386` from the previous does not get removed, so I had to manually remove it, then the installation worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `wine-stable` on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 install -

1. Open **Software and Updates** and tick the box on the "Community-maintained free and open source software (universe)" line, then click **Close** and when the box pops up, click **Reload**
2. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable`
5. `wine --version` returns `wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)`

Just verified this in a virtual machine

Comment: Thanks for confirming, it however still does not work for me

Comment: However after adding universe as suggested in the comments, I am able to add successfully.

Comment: Adding universe is step 1 in my instructions!

Answer (score -1):

on **Ubuntu 22.04** solved this issue by installing **wine32** and **wine64** packages