# Cannot install Wine on Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: command-line, wine, mono

After installing per the [installation instructions from Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Staring Wine fails:

```
wine start /unix %f
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: Invalid window handle.
```

This is the error code I get when I try to open Wine in Terminal. I first ran Wİne on Terminal and it said it couldn't find Mono and Gecko and said it can install it for me. I clicked ok and it installed Mono without any problem but with Gecko it got an error and couldn't install it. It was able to install it in the second try and I ran Wine again, but I got the error above. Did I do anything wrong? I should also mention, when I try to open it from /usr/share/applications nothing happens.

Comment: It's been suggested you use the solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/1205596/197910

Answer (score -1):

Use the [installation instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) from Wine instead:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: I already did this.

Comment: OK! Good to know! It's wise to tell us what you've done, so we don't have to reinvent the wheel. Were there any error messages?

Comment: @K7AAY your method is absolutely OK for < 18.04 LTS. But here Wine HQ has [poor quality of the documentation](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48513), shame on them!