# Can't install wine stable on Ubuntu 19.10 (depends on wine-stable)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

I am trying to install wine on my Ubuntu 19.10. Actually, I am coming from Ubuntu 19.04, but I upgraded to 19.10 in November.

Long story short, I know of this repository which should contain everything I need to make a proper installation: `deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main`

The problem is that when I try to do the installation `apt install winehq-stable`, apt throws an error and stops:

```
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
```

I have double checked if there are some old wine repositories, but there are not. I have checked for previously installed wine packages (using synaptic, searching for "wine"), and found nothing.

I have followed a few guides, but I still can't do the installation.

I am stuck in a dependency hell, but how do I find the cause?

**EDIT:** Wine installation on Ubuntu 19.10 is different from any previous release, because, they say, `libfaudio0` was not available on Ubuntu's repositories prior to 19.10. So old questions or instructions suggesting to use external repositories are outdated.

This is what I did:

- By following a few (outdated, but I didn't know that) guides, I have tried to install wine using old repositories. It didn't work.

  - When I have found out that Ubuntu 19.10 had different instructions I have cleaned up my `sources.list`, so now I don't have those old/wrong repositories anymore.
  - I have tried to manually remove every package that I have found on my system that could be related with wine.
  - At this point, I thought that my system was cleaned of all of the previous attempts. I was wrong.
- So I have tried a new installation with the official instructions:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
  sudo apt-key add winehq.key
  sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
  sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
  ```

And this is the complete output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**EDIT 2:** This is my apt sources list:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-proposed universe restricted main multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/insomnia.list:deb https://dl.bintray.com/getinsomnia/Insomnia /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list:deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_19.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-disco.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as I can't reproduce your problem on clean Ubuntu 19.10 VM while following official guide from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu .

Comment: Nope. I have already checked my repositories, making sure that I had nothing that could create conflicts with the winehq repository. They are ok (I have 4-5 external repositories for other software, plus the one from `winehq`.

Comment: The issue is probably due to something that I have installed in the past, and that is giving me dependency issues now. Maybe I've even tried -unsuccessfully- to install wine with ubuntu 19.04 and gave up (I honestly don't remember)

Comment: Then you have to try to descent up to real problematic package. Try something like `sudo apt-get install winehq-stable wine-stable` and add complete error to the question body.

Comment: Apart from some italian lines, the only useful thing is `winehq-stable : Dipende: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)`. No other packages are indicated. Do you still need the whole output?

Comment: To be more clear - you have to run an analysis as it was done for [18.04 LTS by me before](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205596/66509).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Not really, as any guide suggesting to use the opensuse repositories should be valid until ubuntu 19.04, but outdated for ubuntu >= 19.10. I have updated my original question though.

Comment: Thanks Melebius that translation tip is good to know! I'm updating my question with english output. Also, there are no held packages (I've checked with `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: @ToX82 I have tried to install Wine-stable on 19.10 using their [official guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) yesterday and ended with success. Please show the full list of all repositories in your system with `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Also please note that [`libfaudio0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libfaudio0)  exists in 19.10 repository.

Comment: @N0rbert the list is too long for a comment, so I have edited the original question with my repositories.

Comment: @ToX82 I'll recommend switching to the *Main server* with address `archive.ubuntu.com` (use Software & Updates or  `software-properties-gtk`), then update package cache with `sudo apt update` and install all upgrades with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. And finally retry Wine installation.

Comment: I've tried, now my ubuntu repositorires are all pointing to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`... but still I can't install Wine, as I'm having the same error as before. (I'm switching back to the italian mirrors, as they seems to be a bit faster, at least from my connection)

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem and the issue for me was that, for some reason, the package `libvdpau1:i386` conflicted with other packages I had (audacity, gimp, vlc, etc.).

What worked for me was to:

```
sudo apt install libvdpau1:i386
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
sudo apt-get install audacity gimp vlc ... # Reinstall the packages that got removed on step 1
```