# Ubuntu 18.04: Wine Dependencies?

Tags: wine

I've followed this guide to installing wine: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

When running: `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried running the commands for bionic instead of eoan with no success. I tried following this guide with no success: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-wine-5-0-stable-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to Linux. Just came over from Windows.

This question did not help: [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

This is how it went:

```
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
[sudo] password for skylar: 
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38.5 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [73.8 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [265 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [196 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [17.6 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [449 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [41.5 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,980 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42.1 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [111 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,964 kB in 2s (1,246 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
skylar@Eden:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
xserver-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 all [upgradable from: 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3]
xserver-xephyr/bionic-updates 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3]
xwayland/bionic-updates 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3]
```

```
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease       
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
skylar@Eden:~$ upgrade
upgrade: command not found
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwup1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  xserver-common xserver-xephyr xwayland
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,813 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 165284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-common_2%3a1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-common (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) over (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xephyr_2%3a1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xephyr (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) over (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xwayland_2%3a1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xwayland (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) over (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up xserver-common (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) ...
Setting up xserver-xephyr (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) ...
Setting up xwayland (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwup1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
skylar@Eden:~$ wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
2020-03-22 11:57:10 URL:https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key [1089/1089] -> "Release.key" [1]
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
OK
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'

Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Get:6 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1,562 B]
Get:7 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages [21.8 kB]
Fetched 23.4 kB in 1s (17.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:6 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                
skylar@Eden:~$ # Stable branch     
skylar@Eden:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
skylar@Eden:~$ 
skylar@Eden:~$ #Development branch     
skylar@Eden:~$ #sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel
skylar@Eden:~$ 
skylar@Eden:~$ #Staging branch     
skylar@Eden:~$ #sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: Haven't been able to find an answer anywhere; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nope that gave me the same result I think.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Do you have 18.04 LTS (bionic) or 19.10 (eoan)?

Comment: 18.04.4 bionic. Sorry for the noobishness I'm brand new to all this.

Comment: The linked guide tells you to replace the string `eoan` with `bionic` for your release (18.04). You missed that and added the wrong repository.

Comment: You have to run `sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'`.

Comment: It's working now, thanks everyone! I'm not even entirely sure what I did, I just tried a bunch of stuff and Wine is now functioning. I wish I understood this stuff better but I'm glad it's working now!