# Unable to install WineHQ (all guides not resolving issue)

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wine

May I please have assistance with installing WineHQ on Ubuntu 18.04
I have spent the last few hours going over the WineHQ official site's guide for install, and multiple other 3rd party linux based websites. I continue to get

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

However, every fix I have come across (even on this site) results in

```
The following packages have been kept back.
```

Any suggestions?

As some background, I have had everything installed once I got this machine. Wine, Play On Linux, Steam, and some other things. Everything was working fine until a recent update caused my screen to not wake up from suspend/sleep. Then I continued to get OS error messages that I would "report" but then when checking my activity log, nothing was showing as an issue. So I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)