# Having trouble downloading winehq ;(

Tags: wine

The error looks like this. 
->

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 5.5~bionic)
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried everything that pops up on youtube, but nothing seems to work..

Comment: You shouldn't installing winehq-staging instead of winehq-stable. What is your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I have ubuntu 18.04, and i don't know what stable or staging does, but they both have the same error. well the three things have the same error. stable, staging, and the other one

Comment: If anyone has the same problem try deleting the ppa, and then install wine-stable, or any. I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)