# Downloading of WineHQ

Tags: apt, wine, ppa

Hello i am new to Ubuntu.

So the problem i have is that I use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and WineHQ 5.0.

The WineHQ installation is as 64 bit version, i followed the instruction from https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux/

However, at the 11th step, i encountered with this message "E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file."

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: no. actually the wine is already in the system. In the command, i typed WIne -- version, and it tells me its Wine 5.0 . That would mean that I'm done adding wine into the system right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: If you *really* want Wine 5.0, then simply use a newer release of Ubuntu. Then it's just `sudo apt install wine`. You can avoid all that mucking about haywiring your system to put new software on an old OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ppa is too old (isn't updated since 2017, no release file for 18.04). You should remove it with ppa-purge (`sudo apt install ppa-purge` and `ppa-purge http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu` ).

The WINE installed on your system is maybe from ubuntu repositories. WINE is a rare case because unlike other software in Linux, it is recommended to install WINE from the official website: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu Follow this guide and install the stable branch (it will replace the current wine by the official wine).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj08gKkHDpY 
To properly launch my wine, i had to command winecfg.
Hope this helps.