# Can't install the newest Wine on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, system-installation, wine

So I'm operating on Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever I try to install the Wine this is what I get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.0~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when I try to add `$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64` I get this.

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libfaudio0 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and I am not the best with it, so I'd really appreciate some assistance with what this issue means and how to correct it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Ubuntu 18.04 method of installing Wine 5.  It appears on [this website](https://linuxhint.com/install_wine_ubuntu/).

I will detail the steps:

Enable 32 bit support:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add repositories for Wine:
Download the GPG key of the official Wine package repository:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

Add the Wine GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

Add the official Wine package repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Download the OpenSUSE Wine repository’s GPG key:

```
wget -nc https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key
```

Add the GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key add Release.key
```

Add the OpenSUSE Wine repository:

```
echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list
```

Update the APT package repository cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

You’re ready to install Wine 5:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Press Y and then press Enter

Once Wine 5 is installed, you can configure it.

```
winecfg
```

Comment: It seems to have worked, although there seems to be one small issue.                                                                                                             $ winecfg
wine: '/home/user/.wine' is a 64-bit installation, it cannot be used with a 32-bit wineserver.

Comment: I am working on this and hope to get back with a solution.