# How do I resolve "bash: ./SupportTool.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"?

Tags: wine

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4, and am trying to download Divinity 2. I have it installed, but whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

> "bash: ./SupportTool.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

I got the following results when checking for compatibility:

> arch: x86_64
>
> file: EoCApp.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows

Is there a way to make this compatible? Please let me know what other details I can provide.

Thank you,

Andrew

Comment: Use wine for launching Windows apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't launch native Windows application through vanilla Ubuntu, you have to use WINE in order to execute them.

> Wine (originally an acronym for "**Wine Is Not an Emulator**") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, & BSD.

To install please refer to official documentation https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu, alternatively execute following command on terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

You can then launch the application through Wine

```
wine SupportTool.exe
```

You can check Wine's compatibility for Divinity 2 → https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=18266

Comment: Your great method of Wine installation will not work because of [dependency problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/1205550/66509).

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging! Thank you so much! I have fun new problems to troubleshoot, but this worked!