# ubuntu 18.04 Wine 5.0 various workarounds didn't work for me

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, wine, dependencies

I've followed the WineHQ guide than tried again adding this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnutls30:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libxml2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
```

than again following the replay to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

(and a bunch of other stuff, I tried posting the process but it kept getting caught in the spam filter).

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
wine-devel-amd64/eoan 5.9~eoan amd64 [upgradable from: 5.9~bionic]
wine-devel-dbg/eoan 5.9~eoan amd64 [upgradable from: 5.9~bionic]
wine-devel-dev/eoan 5.9~eoan i386 [upgradable from: 5.9~bionic]
wine-devel-i386/eoan 5.9~eoan i386 [upgradable from: 5.9~bionic]
wine-stable-amd64/eoan 5.0.0~eoan amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.4~bionic]
wine-staging-i386/eoan 5.9~eoan i386 [upgradable from: 5.9~bionic]
```

I've tried to force upgrade/install them, from 9 they come down to the 6 that are listed here.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I literally don't know how ubuntu works, if anyone could walk me through this, thanks in advance

-edit

```
$ apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable wine
winehq-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0~eoan
  Version table:
     5.0.0~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4~bionic 500
        500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
     4.0.3~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0~eoan
  Version table:
     5.0.0~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4~bionic 500
        500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
     4.0.3~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
wine:
  Installed: 4.0.4-0ubuntu1~18.04~ricotz0
  Candidate: 4.0.4-0ubuntu1~18.04~ricotz0
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.4-0ubuntu1~18.04~ricotz0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/unstable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/unstable/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @N0rbert no, it's the exact question I posted and said I followed and fail

Comment: Why do you have *eoan* on *bionic*? Please add output of `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable wine` to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244001/edit).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED, FIXED, RESOLVED etc. In the question title. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess of repositories.

Remove wrong ones with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main' 

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/unstable
```

and it will become fixed.

Comment: that solved the dependencies problem thank you, but it's still the wine-4.0.4 version, is it normal?

Comment: You can optionally purge `wine` package and install `winehq-stable` instead.