# Install winehq-staging on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, lutris

I have been trying to install winehq-staging (to use with lutris) on Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed the standard steps, but always end up with:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 5.10~focal)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, because it does not tell me which dependencies are actually missing!

What can I do to succesfully install `winehq-staging`?

**Edit:**

I tried both the options commented by @N0rbert and @bhordupur, but both did not work to solve my issues. I get the exact same error message. I did, however, also run `sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64` to figure out which packages are missing, which gave the following output:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libvkd3d1 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know what this output means precisely? It reads like I might be unable to install these dependencies in order to get winehq-stable to work?

Comment: you need to install the deps packages

Comment: Install these deps: 
`sudo apt-get install libgnutls30:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libxml2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386`

Comment: @bhordupur: thanks for replying! I ran the command you gave me, and apparently, all these had been installed already. I still get the same error message as in the original post. Is there any way to find out which dependencies are actually missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04) . We need to thank "Rosanne DiMesio " again for her great effort on writing of fully reproducible manuals for WineHQ.

Comment: try this: `https://paste.centos.org/view/ca336870`

Comment: all-right, so I tried both these options  but both did not work! I have updated my post stating which error I get now.

Comment: have you tried to install 
`Update the package index:
# sudo apt-get update
Install libvkd3d1 deb package:
# sudo apt-get install libvkd3d1`

What happens when you try to install the above pck?

Comment: what versions of gcc do you have? do you have multiple versions of gcc? What is the default one in your system?

Comment: Thanks for replying! When I tried to install that last one, I got the error `E: Package 'libvkd3d1' has no installation candidate`. If I run `gcc -v`, it tells me that `gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)`.

Comment: @karel, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, nothing in those answers works for me. I have to somehow install libc6 (>= 2.29), lingcc-s1 (>= 3.0) amd libvkd3d1 (>= 1.0), but apparantly they are not installable (see updated post)?