# Impossible to reinstall WineHQ

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

*(EDIT: this question was suggested to be answered with [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04) but, although the problem is the same one, I see the given solution in this post better than the other one (more efficient)! So please keep this question, or move the solution to the other one, so other users can know this solution!)*

For some unknwon reason, wine stuck when loading any Windows program. So I uninstalled it for reinstalling it again. I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

When I try to reinstall it, [following the winehq.org steps](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), in the last step, it says:

```
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.2~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried to install manually the dependencies, but arrived to a lot of packages that "won't be installed". Of course, googled it. Tried, then:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Tried as well unholding two packages that have anything to do with this, but nothing.

Then:

```
sudo aptitude -f install winehq-stable
```

I'm grateful because aptitude made an effort to solve this, but all the solutions that it proposes include:

```
     Keep the following packages in the current version:
2)     wine-stable [not installed]                          
3)     wine-stable-i386:i386 [not installed]                
4)     winehq-stable [not installed]
```

I don't know how to say it that *I want to update* those from *"not installed"* to *any that requires to be installed*.

I've tried, as well, fixing broken packages through Synaptics (and said that succeeded), and some other solutions I've found on the Internet that I can't remember now, but I'll tell you if suggested.

The package is not installed now (every attemp to purge or something won't work because this).

Any ideas? I want to believe this can be solved without reinstalling the whole OS.

Comment: Did it give you any error messages when you setup the wine repositories?  What is the output of when you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thank you very much to both! the apt update said nothing (the errors came just when trying to install), and N0rbert, your post revealed what was happening (not knowing what is going on is always 50% of the frustration to me): Ubuntu 18.04 nor WineHQ have the package libfaudio0, available since Ubuntu 19.10. I didn't update to Ubuntu 20.04 yet because I prefer Ubuntu to offer the upgrade by itself, but it hasn't done it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install *libfaudio0* as well, in your Ubuntu 18.04 installation using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

You may also need to enable 32 bit architecture, if it isn't enabled using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

So for the whole installation process:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key; sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Finally installed and working! Incredibly efficient solution 