# Trying (and failing) to install Wine

Tags: wine

I know this is (probably) gonna be tagged as a duplicate, as were some other question about this, that I read and weren't the answer I need. So I decided to try opening a new question.

Following the instructions in the Winehq website I get the errors in this paste:

https://pastebin.com/HDwWxnkP

As shown there, I don't have the dependencies and apt won't install them in any way I tried.

How can I install the dependencies and why Winehq doesn't show us exactly how to do that? Clearly, it was mentioned enough times that their team is aware of this by now. I'm not trying to sound salty or anything, I just don't understand why there is so little info on their site about how to instal the dependencies.

They link a FAQ page on the bottom of the instructions and in the FAQ page is only said to work dependencies backwards. Tried that and it didn't work...

Sorry for the long post, I hope someone can help.

Comment: I use lutris to deal with wine (https://lutris.net/downloads/)

Comment: Is it possible to install Wine using Lutris? In the site it says Lutris need Wine to play games...

Comment: lutris will install whatever wine version you need in a wrapper for the program you are trying to install so for mtga for example I would go to (https://lutris.net/games/magic-the-gathering-arena/) click on the lnstall button for whatever virsion I want then I get an xdg-open thing I click open on then lutris opens and starts the install script for the program

Comment: Oh. That sounds like just what I need. I'll definitely try. Thanks.

Comment: Well... It can load the game alright, but didn't really install Wine since I can't load it from the terminal. It just loads the game from Lutris. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it did install a lutris version of wine but if you just want to install wine ubuntu has a version in the repo so "sudo apt install wine64" for a 64bit system and "sudo apt install wine32" for 32 bit and "wine --version" to see what version is installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: After looking into each and every comment there, I finaly got wine to install. They sure could make this proccess a little less convoluted. Thanks for all the help. Whoever knows how to close this, please do so. Bonus point if you could also point me in the directions of doing that.