# Unable to install winehq on Ubuntu 20.04 I got error stating:- E:unable to correct, you have unmet dependencies

Tags: wine

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.3~groovy)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks like you are unwisely trying to install a non-Ubuntu version of Wine that is incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. That counts as requesting "*an impossible situation*." Pick a release of Wine that is compatible with your release of Ubuntu. The version in the Ubuntu repositories has been tested and debugged -- it's compatible (and easier to install than your current method).

Comment: but i tried every version of that pakage but still  got the same at everytime

Comment: Different versions of `winehq-stable` would, of course, depend upon different versions of  `wine-stable`. If you get the same output (`Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.3~groovy)`) everytime, that suggests that either you tried the same wrong release each time...or you failed to clean up after your first failure. Um, a package with the name `groovy` (Groovy = 20.10)  in the version won't be compatible with an older (Focal = 20.04) system.

Comment: will you please help me out . how to clean completely that

Comment: Edit your question: You must clearly list every step you followed to add the Wine repositories and install the (incompatible) software. How you remove something cleanly depends upon how you originally installed it. Refer your apt history in /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log if you do not recall exactly what you did.

Comment: Question: Why are you trying to install Wine from the upstream WineHQ instead of using the very good version that's already in the Ubuntu repositories? Is there some feature you want that's only available in the upstream package? Or did you just not know about the easy way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)