# How to install wine32 after upgrading kubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, wine, 32-bit

I just upgraded my ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and I'm not able to install 32 bit version of wine. I did the followings:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: wine-stable:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install libwine:i386 manually I get:

```
$ sudo apt install libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libsane1:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Then I tried to add all depedencies manually:

```
$ sudo apt install libwine:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libxml2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not going to be installed
 libldap-2.4-2:i386 : Depends: libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.5.6) but it is not going to be installed
 librsvg2-2 : Depends: libcroco3 (>= 0.6.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: librsvg2-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried first without the winehq repository, but the result was the same.

**EDIT:**

I've tried everything mentioned in [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)
But it leads always to unmet depedencies.

**EDIT 2021-01-06 17:39 UTC+1:**

Some additional info:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep wine
ii  libkwineffects11:amd64  4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1         amd64  KDE window manager effects library
rc  playonlinux             4.2.10-a~xenial~Noobslab.com  all    This program is a front-end for wine. 
rc  wine-devel              5.19~xenial                   amd64  WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
rc  wine-devel-amd64        5.19~xenial                   amd64  WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
rc  wine-devel-i386:i386    5.19~xenial                   i386   WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
rc  wine1.6                 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2           amd64  Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)

$ apt-cache policy | grep -i wine
 500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
     release o=obs://build.opensuse.org/Emulators:Wine:Debian/xUbuntu_18.04,n=xUbuntu_18.04,l=Emulators:Wine:Debian,c=

$ grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
```

Probably it is important, that it's about **kubuntu**.

**EDIT 2021-01-07 09:13 UTC+1:**

Further package info:

```
$ grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include=*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list:deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./

$ aptitude search ~o
i   audio-recorder                            - Audio recorder for GNOME and Unity Desktops.        
i   dropbox                                   - cloud synchronization engine - CLI and Nautilus exte
i   fvd-module                                - nimbus web                                          
i   google-chrome-stable                      - The web browser from Google                         
i A gradle-6.7.1                              - Gradle is a Groovy based build system               
i A gradle-ppa                                - Gradle is a Groovy based build system               
i   grub-customizer                           - Grub Customizer - A graphical Grub2/BURG configurati
i A gstreamer0.10-plugins-base                - GStreamer plugins from the "base" set               
i A gstreamer0.10-plugins-good                - GStreamer plugins from the "good" set               
i   icaclient                                 - Citrix Workspace app for Linux                      
i   indicator-kdeconnect                      - Indicator for KDE Connect                           
i   kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer               - graphics file format plugins for Strigi Desktop Sear
i A launchpad-getkeys                         - Import missing GPG keys automatically               
i   libdvdcss-dev                             - library for accessing encrypted DVDs - development f
i   libdvdcss2                                - library for accessing encrypted DVDs                
i A libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0           - GStreamer libraries from the "base" set             
i A libgstreamer0.10-0                        - Core GStreamer libraries and elements               
i   libical1a                                 - iCalendar library implementation in C (runtime)     
i A libicu65                                  - International Components for Unicode                
i   libkcddb4                                 - CDDB library for KDE Platform (runtime)             
i   libkcompactdisc4                          - CD drive library for KDE Platform (runtime)         
i   libkf5calendarcore5                       - calendar access framework                           
i   libkf5gpgmepp-pthread5                    - c++ wrapper library for gpgme                       
i   libkf5gpgmepp5                            - c++ wrapper library for gpgme                       
i   libkf5kdgantt2-5                          - Gantt widget - library                              
i   libkf5libkleo5                            - KDE PIM cryptographic library                       
i   libkf5mime5                               - library for handling MIME data                      
i   libkf5pimtextedit5                        - library that provides a textedit with PIM-specific f
i   libkf5qgpgme5                             - library for GpgME++ integration with Qt             
i   libobasis6.3-base                         - Base module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2                
i   libobasis6.3-calc                         - Calc module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2                
i   libobasis6.3-core                         - Core module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2                
i   libobasis6.3-draw                         - Draw module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2                
i   libobasis6.3-en-us                        - Language module for LibreOffice 6.3, language en_US 
i   libobasis6.3-extension-beanshell-script-p - Script provider for BeanShell extension for LibreOff
i   libobasis6.3-extension-javascript-script- - Script provider for JavaScript extension for LibreOf
i   libobasis6.3-extension-mediawiki-publishe - MediaWiki publisher extension for LibreOffice 6.3 .2
i   libobasis6.3-extension-nlpsolver          - NLPSolver extension for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2        
i   libobasis6.3-extension-pdf-import         - PDF import extension for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2       
i   libobasis6.3-extension-report-builder     - Report Builder extension for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2   
i   libobasis6.3-firebird                     - Firebird module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2            
i   libobasis6.3-gnome-integration            - GNOME integration module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2   
i   libobasis6.3-graphicfilter                - Graphic filter module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2      
i   libobasis6.3-hu                           - Language module for LibreOffice 6.3, language hu .2.
i   libobasis6.3-images                       - Images module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libobasis6.3-impress                      - Impress module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2             
i   libobasis6.3-kde-integration              - KDE integration module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2     
i   libobasis6.3-librelogo                    - LibreLogo toolbar for LibreOffice 6.3 Writer .2.2   
i   libobasis6.3-libreofficekit-data          - Libreofficekit data files for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2  
i   libobasis6.3-math                         - Math module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2                
i   libobasis6.3-ogltrans                     - OpenGL slide transitions module for LibreOffice 6.3 
i   libobasis6.3-onlineupdate                 - Online update module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2       
i   libobasis6.3-ooofonts                     - 3rd party free fonts for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2       
i   libobasis6.3-ooolinguistic                - Linguistic module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2          
i   libobasis6.3-postgresql-sdbc              - PostgreSQL Connector driver for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2
i   libobasis6.3-python-script-provider       - Script provider for Python for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2 
i   libobasis6.3-pyuno                        - Pyuno module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2               
i   libobasis6.3-writer                       - Writer module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libobasis6.3-xsltfilter                   - XSLT filter samples module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2 
i   libokularcore7                            - libraries for the Okular document viewer            
i   libpng12-0                                - PNG library - runtime                               
i   libpng12-0:i386                           - PNG library - runtime                               
i   libqmobipocket1                           - library for reading Mobipocket documents            
i   libqt5clucene5                            - Qt 5 CLucene module                                 
i   libqt5qml-graphicaleffects                - transitional dummy package for Qt 5 Graphical Effect
i   libreoffice6.3                            - Brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2               
i   libreoffice6.3-base                       - Base brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2          
i   libreoffice6.3-calc                       - Calc brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2          
i   libreoffice6.3-debian-menus               - LibreOffice 6.3 desktop integration                 
i   libreoffice6.3-dict-en                    - En dictionary for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libreoffice6.3-dict-es                    - Es dictionary for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libreoffice6.3-dict-fr                    - Fr dictionary for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libreoffice6.3-dict-hu                    - Hu dictionary for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2              
i   libreoffice6.3-draw                       - Draw brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2          
i   libreoffice6.3-en-us                      - Brand language module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2      
i   libreoffice6.3-hu                         - Brand language module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2      
i   libreoffice6.3-impress                    - Impress brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2       
i   libreoffice6.3-math                       - Math brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2          
i   libreoffice6.3-ure                        - UNO Runtime Environment .2.2                        
i   libreoffice6.3-writer                     - Writer brand module for LibreOffice 6.3 .2.2        
i   libssl1.0.2                               - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries     
i A libtidy5deb1                              - HTML/XML syntax checker and reformatter - shared lib
i   libunistring0                             - Unicode string library for C                        
i   linux-headers-4.18.20-041820              - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.18.20
i   linux-image-unsigned-4.18.20-041820-gener - Linux kernel image for version 4.18.20 on 64 bit x86
i   linux-modules-4.18.20-041820-generic      - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.20 on 64
i   mod-pagespeed-stable                      - Apache 2 module to optimize web content.            
i   numix-icon-theme-circle                   - Numix Circle icons                                  
i   opera                                     - Fast and secure web browser and Internet suite      
i   oracle-java8-installer                    - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8             
i   oracle-java8-set-default                  - Set Oracle JDK 8 as default Java                    
i A php5.6-common                             - documentation, examples and common module for PHP   
i   php5.6-gd                                 - GD module for PHP                                   
i   php5.6-intl                               - Internationalisation module for PHP                 
i   php5.6-mbstring                           - MBSTRING module for PHP                             
i   php5.6-mcrypt                             - libmcrypt module for PHP                            
i   php5.6-mysql                              - MySQL module for PHP                                
i   php5.6-tidy                               - tidy module for PHP                                 
i   php5.6-xml                                - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP   
i A php7.1-common                             - documentation, examples and common module for PHP   
i   php7.1-gd                                 - GD module for PHP                                   
i   php7.1-intl                               - Internationalisation module for PHP                 
i   php7.1-mbstring                           - MBSTRING module for PHP                             
i   php7.1-mcrypt                             - libmcrypt module for PHP                            
i   php7.1-mysql                              - MySQL module for PHP                                
i   php7.1-tidy                               - tidy module for PHP                                 
i   php7.1-xml                                - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP   
i A php7.3-common                             - documentation, examples and common module for PHP   
i   php7.3-mysql                              - MySQL module for PHP                                
i A php7.4-common                             - documentation, examples and common module for PHP   
i A php7.4-mysql                              - MySQL module for PHP                                
i   postgresql-9.5                            - object-relational SQL database, version 9.5 server  
i   postgresql-client-9.5                     - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5               
i   postgresql-contrib-9.5                    - additional facilities for PostgreSQL                
i   postgresql-doc-9.5                        - documentation for the PostgreSQL database management
i   skypeforlinux                             - Skype keeps the world talking, for free.            
i   smplayer-skins                            - Skin themes for SMPlayer                            
i   teamviewer                                - Remote control and meeting solution.                
i   viber                                     - Free Text & Calls.                                  
i   y-ppa-manager                             - Y PPA Manager                                       
i   zoom                                      - Zoom, #1 Video Conferencing and Web Conferencing Ser

$ apt-cache policy libgd3:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libcroco3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libgd3:i386:
  Telepítve: (nincs)
  Jelölt:    2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4
  Verziótáblázat:
     2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     2.2.5-4 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
libgnutls30:i386:
  Telepítve: (nincs)
  Jelölt:    3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4
  Verziótáblázat:
     3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
     3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     3.5.18-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
libcroco3:
  Telepítve: 0.6.12-2
  Jelölt:    0.6.12-2
  Verziótáblázat:
 *** 0.6.12-2 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:
  Telepítve: 2.36.11-2
  Jelölt:    2.36.11-2
  Verziótáblázat:
 *** 2.36.11-2 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT 2021-01-07 10:02 UTC+1:**

Some steps requested by @NOrbert. The commands did not do anything as updated two irrelevant packages: libwavpack1, wavpack.

**EDIT 2021-01-07 10:59 UTC+1:**

Attempt with aptitude, no success:

```
$ aptitude install wine32
"wine32" is a virtual package provided by:
  winehq-staging winehq-stable winehq-devel wine32:i386 
You must choose one to install.
Unable to apply some actions, aborting

$ aptitude install wine32:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libatomic1:i386{a} 
  libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} 
  libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcdparanoia0:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} 
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} 
  libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libgd3:i386{ab} libgl1:i386{a} 
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} 
  libglx-mesa0:i386{a} libglx0:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} 
  libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} 
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libhogweed4:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libicu60:i386{a} libidn2-0:i386{ab} 
  libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{ab} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} 
  libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} 
  libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm10:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} 
  libopus0:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} 
  libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libsane1:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} 
  libsensors4:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{ab} libtasn1-6:i386{a} 
  libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libunistring2:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} 
  libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwine:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-shm0:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{ab} libxpm4:i386{a} 
  libxslt1.1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} wine32:i386 
0 packages upgraded, 95 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 73.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 627 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.3.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4) but 2.3.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libjbig0 : Breaks: libjbig0:i386 (!= 2.1-3.1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) but 2.1-3.1build1 is to be installed
 libjbig0:i386 : Breaks: libjbig0 (!= 2.1-3.1build1) but 2.1-3.1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 is installed
 libxml2 : Breaks: libxml2:i386 (!= 2.9.10+dfsg-5+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3) but 2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
 libxml2:i386 : Breaks: libxml2 (!= 2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3) but 2.9.10+dfsg-5+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 is installed
 libssl1.1 : Breaks: libssl1.1:i386 (!= 1.1.1i-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4) but 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7 is to be installed
 libssl1.1:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.1 (!= 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7) but 1.1.1i-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 is installed
 libidn2-0 : Breaks: libidn2-0:i386 (!= 2.3.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) but 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libidn2-0:i386 : Breaks: libidn2-0 (!= 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2) but 2.3.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                                      
1)      libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
2)      libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
3)      libgnutls30:i386 [Not Installed]                                                         
4)      libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
5)      libidn2-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                           
6)      libjbig0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
7)      libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
8)      libsane1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
9)      libsasl2-modules:i386 [Not Installed]                                                    
10)     libssl1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                           
11)     libtiff5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
12)     libwine:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
13)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
14)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                          
15)     wine32:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                               
16)     libwine:i386 recommends libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3)                                         
17)     libsasl2-2:i386 recommends libsasl2-modules:i386 (>= 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1)



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: @NOrbert Although the problem is similar, no one of the answers worked.

Comment: OK, let's analyze it here, bit deeper. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep wine` and `apt-cache policy | grep -i wine`  .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @karel There is no broken packages at all on my system.

Comment: Let's get list of all repositories by `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` and also list of locally installed packages by `aptitude search ~o`. Add `apt-cache policy libgd3:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libcroco3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0` .

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: ... E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @N0rbert I added the requested info to the question. Do you follow this question? I.e. do you get a notification anyway if I edit my question?

Comment: From now I follow the question. Please add output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`. Then run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (to get newest dependencies) followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @N0rbert They didn't do anything relevant. What is suspicious for me, that I have an old kernel running (4.18.20-041820-generic), but Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS is coming with kernel 5.4. But I guess, it shouldn't affect wine at all.

Comment: I see. Please try `sudo aptitude install wine32` , `sudo aptitude install libwine:i386` .

Comment: @N0rbert I did, unfortunately no success. Note, that I had to truncate some previous info. I reached the maximum body size of the question allowed by StackExchange.

Comment: @Matigo, your reputation rising is great, but this is not a duplicate as you can read from my below answer. Please remove it. @ others this is not a duplicate, this is comprehensive issue because of deb.sury.org packages. It took long time to detect and fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the real root of the problem. It is caused by php-*sury* packages.

You have to save list of them by

```
dpkg -l | grep "deb.sury.org" | awk '{print $2}' > deb-sury-packages-list.txt
```

and then carefully downgrade each of them to the version from official repository. You have to use Synaptic for this. Or by using commands like `sudo apt-get install libssl1.1=1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7 libssl1.1:i386=1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.7` .

Then retry installing Wine.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks. It works!!! How did you find out?

Comment: Great! I obtained the solution by analyzing your commands output.

Answer (score 0):

Installing older/different versions of Wine than the latest ones from the repositories in Debian/Ubuntu system is a pain in the rear extremity.

Plan B: consider hopping over to Manjaro, if it's possible for you to do so. Why? Because the Manjaro version of the Wine package comes bundled IN A SINGLE PACKAGE, and you install it using A SINGLE COMMAND:

```
sudo pacman -U /local_path/wine-staging-5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
or, in the case you miss dependencies..
sudo pacman -Sy /path/wine...
(I think that's the command... I'm not in Manjaro right now,
the Sy command will download the dependencies for you 
WITHOUT performing a full system upgrade, only the packages you need...
pacman -U is the equivalent of sudo dpkg -i , for manual install)
```

OK. If hopping over to Arch/Manjaro is NOT a possibility for you, these below are the steps for MANUALLY installing older versions of Wine on Debian/Ubuntu-based distros:

1. Let's say you want to install Wine version 4.1 (one of the last versions of Wine before the Wineprefix size increased from 100 MB straight to 600 MB, without no additional benefits and no avoidance of the usual bugs from the last 10 years...)
   Go to https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/
   and download all packages that have 4.1 in their name (they should have the same Date to them)

In the case of Wine 4.1 (the version that I've found to be the optimal one) these are the packages you need. You always will need FIVE packages in total.

```
winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
```

2. Installation order. Here comes the tricky part, after you do it the 1st time it should be easier the next times. First, you install the biggest i386 package, always. Then, you install the small i386 package. Then, install the big amd64 package, and the small amd64 package. The last to be installed should be winehq (which only comes in amd64 form)

Below is a copy of my bash history with the order of commands I used to do this in shortest time.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
...
winecfg    <used to create the initial Wine prefix>
<use these ones below to reassure that you have all libs installed correctly>
...
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg  <to test if 32-bit is working OK>
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg  <to test if 64-bit is working OK>
<you should not see errors in the terminal of the type
"but the wrong architecture is being used" >
```

Notice how you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

every single time each package is installed. That will guarantee that the individual dependencies to each package are installed and configured, before you install the next package. (this is only needed the 1st time you do this... after that, you can put all these dependencies, store them in a Backup location, and install them all-at-once using sudo dpkg -i /path/*.deb )

3. Sometimes, and I don't understand why this happens, you won't be able to use Wine 64 bits, or you won't be able to use Wine 32 bits, one of the two. If that happens, simply re-install one of the big Wine packages again (depending if you need amd64 or i386)

   sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb

It's very unfortunate that Wine has been distributed like this on Debian/Ubuntu system, it's an overcomplicated process with a lot of time wasted. The way Manjaro does it should become the official way Wine is distributed from now on.