# Unmet dependencies while installing wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am trying to install wine for the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) that I am using via [the guidelines provided by the wine website](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

These are the steps I have made:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main'
```

And now the last command in the process seems to have an issue that I have not been able to figure out.
The command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

After I insert this command I get this:

```
"Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~groovy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)

Comment: Why did you use "groovy" if you have "focal" (20.04)?

Comment: @PabloBianchi nailed the problem: Seems like you unwisely tried to install the "newest" version instead of the version appropriate for your older 20.04 release of Ubuntu. Back out your failed install: Uninstall the packages, delete the source you added. Then start over, installing Wine for 20.04 (Focal). Of course, the Ubuntu repositories already have the correct version of Wine; the extra steps required to install from upstream (winehq) sources are optional.

Comment: I hit this because I was confused by https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and I installed the 20.10 repo instead of the 20.04 repo. :)