# unmet dependencies: winehq-stable

Tags: wine

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Steps according to https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu:

1. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
2. wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
3. sudo apt-key add winehq.key
   Until here: everything is fine.
4. sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
   Output:

> sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable [sudo] password
> for XXXX:          Reading package lists... Done Building dependency
> tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not
> be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
> situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
> required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
> Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
> E: Unable to correct problems,
> you have held broken packages**

**Suggested by other users:**

1.Run Synaptic -> fix broken packages -> did not work

2.Run Synaptic -> find all wine dependencies -> delete all -> repeat installation process -> did not work

Help!

Comment: Before installing, run `sudo apt update`to update the package "database" with information from the new repository, so apt van resolve dependencies.

Comment: Are you using a compatible architecture (for i386)?

Comment: please paste the output of `apt-cache policy wine-stable`. I see a mention of focal (the code name for 20.04) in the output, which is odd.

Comment: Remove everything you have done and just run `sudo apt install wine-stable`  The universe repo has version  3.0-1ubuntu1

Comment: Leave step 1 in though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install wine from winehq.org on Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-from-winehq-org-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04-lts) You should "thank" Rosanne DiMesio for her "great" guide of official WineHQ Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link, here is what I did:

1. Synaptic -> removed all wine repositories
2. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. Removing previous WineHQ repository:

`sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main`

5. Adding other repositories:

`wget -q https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -`

`sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'`

6. `sudo apt-get update`

But!

The final suggested step with wine-stable:

7. `sudo apt install --install-recommends **winehq-stable**`

did not work - it said that Linux could not locate the package

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

The final suggested step - with wine-devel:

7. `sudo apt install --install-recommends **winehq-devel**`

.. worked!