# No matter what I do, I get a broken package problem when trying to install wine

Tags: wine

So I have been trying to install wine relentlessly over the past few days. However, I get this problem of unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The version of ubuntu that I am running is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

[A Screenshot of my software and updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auPRZ.png)
I have tried removing/purging wine, cleaning up the packages and reinstalling again but I get the same problem. I'm banging my head against the wall here, however, I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: https://www.linuxscrew.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install wine from winehq.org on Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-from-winehq-org-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: More information about what version of wine you are trying to install is needed. You have a bionic system but you seem to be installing from a focal repo. Unless you specifically need advanced wine features, I suggest removing everything you have done related to wine and just doing a `sudo apt install wine-stable`. In bionic you will get version 3 of wine, you are trying to install version 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)