# how to install wine at Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine

I have tried recommendations from [Can't install Wine Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097724/cant-install-wine-ubuntu-18-04) and from other answers, as follows (in my translation from Czech)

```
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key
File ‘winehq.key’ already there; not retrieving.
[sudo] password for as_a_root: 
OK
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ 
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
Hit:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:3 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6 259 B]
Get:5 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Hit:6 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Get:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [673 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38,8 kB]
Get:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [638 kB]
Get:10 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,1 kB]
Get:12 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]
Get:13 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]
Get:14 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7 972 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Fetched 2 243 kB in 2s (1 058 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease

Hit:4 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
[sudo] password for as_a_root: 
 Backport of SDL2 library
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~cybermax-dexter/+archive/ubuntu/sdl2-backport
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15,9 kB]
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:5 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:6 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [7 836 B]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [7 836 B]
Hit:9 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [5 368 B]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38,7 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,1 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Get:14 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:15 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]
Get:16 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]
Get:17 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7 972 B]
Fetched 963 kB in 2s (458 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
E
 Community members gave me references to answers of other questions [A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-) and [B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04); I am working on it: the [A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-) has shown that I should use aptitude and I have succeeded with installing wine by accepting recommendations from the aptitude. Now, the system offers me using wine as I had been used to, however it responds that it cannot find the *.exe file though I have opened, in the Ubuntu, its directory. In the directory ~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32 (maybe taken from the previous Ubuntu 16.04) I see some files from an old directory mounted as  /media/me/systemXP/WINDOWS/system32, but not the file sol.exe that I use for the test. In the Terminal

```
me@furtherPC:~$ wine "/media/me/systemXP/WINDOWS/system32/sol.exe"
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000004 at address 0x7ead5e16 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
err:seh:start_debugger Couldn't start debugger ("winedbg --auto 8 96") (2)
Read the Wine Developers Guide on how to set up winedbg or another debugger
me@furtherPC:~$ 
me@furtherPC:~$ wine --version
wine-1.6.2
me@furtherPC:~$
```

, the system recommends me some debugging with which I have no experience. Should I try it or uninstall the wine, delete the ~/.wine directory and install wine again? (Now, in that PC, Windows 10 system is installed, besides the Ubuntu 18.04 .) Thanks!

Comment: When I did last time I remember I had to add `sudo dpkg --add-architecture 64 or 86`

Comment: Have you added this `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`?