# How to fix "winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~jammy-1)"

Tags: wine

after using [the tutorial of install wine](https://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-in-ubuntu/) to download wine:

`$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`$ sudo wget -nc -O /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`

and then

`sudo wget -nc -P /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources cause my ubuntu version is 20.04`

`$ sudo apt update`

everything works fine untill the point where I have to download wine stable branch,

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

after doing this I keep getting the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help me out here? I've tried so many forums and methods but none of them worked out.

Comment: Advice: First, completely uninstall all those packages you laboriously installed. Second, delete that apt source you created. Third, run `sudo apt update` because your sources changes. Finally, you can simply install Wine from the Ubuntu Software application (and it will work). You might also complain to the author of that page that their tutorial is both needlessly complex...and doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Wine Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097724/) and [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

This is your ubuntu version not compatible to wine 8.0 for jammy, you must update from 20.04 to 22.04.
It works for me.

Comment: More likely it is installing wrong software when the good stuff is in the Software Store already.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this issue.
Was able to resolve mine after going through the Winehq forum.

- Step 1:
  I had to downgrade the package to the official Ubuntu version with:
  `sudo apt install libgd3=2.3.0-2ubuntu2`
- Step 2:
  I had to run
  `sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-i386:i386`
- Step 3:
  I tried reinstalling the package again and voila problem solved
  `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Tou can refer to steps above was from the Winehq forum..
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=37388