# Cannot install wine on ubuntu 19.10/20.04

Tags: wine, dependencies

I have tried to follow the official guide but unfortunately, there is something wrong with dependencies.

```
$ sudo apt install winehq-stable 

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
```

```
$ sudo apt install wine-stable

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~eoan)
```

```
$ sudo apt install wine-stable-i386

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libsane1:i386
```

... many steps in between, and the last one is quite dangerous to me.

```
$ sudo apt install libpcre2-8-0:i386

The following NEW packages will be installed
  libpcre2-8-0:i386 pinentry-curses
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt adduser (due to apt) coreutils libselinux1 (due to coreutils) dash dpkg (due to dash) debconf (due to dash) tar (due to dpkg) fdisk libmount1 (due to fdisk) findutils grep
  install-info (due to grep) gzip init systemd-sysv (due to init) init-system-helpers (due to init) perl-base (due to init-system-helpers) login libpam0g (due to login)
  libpam-runtime (due to login) libpam-modules (due to login) mount util-linux (due to mount) sed sysvinit-utils
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 1594 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9.097 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful
To continue type in the phrase ‘Yes, do as I say!’
```

How to resolve this dependency hell?

**UPDATE**

Some info on configured repos (also [viewable here](https://pastebin.com/XqJNYU1n)):

```
$ grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/team-xbmc-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thopiekar-ubuntu-cura-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/cura/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/papirus-ubuntu-papirus-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```

---

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

i386
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable

winehq-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0~eoan
  Version table:
     5.0.0~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.3~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0~eoan
  Version table:
     5.0.0~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.3~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe i386 Packages
```

(Also [viewable here](https://pastebin.com/6U2iPTYZ).)

---

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i wine

ii | libkwineffects12 | 4:5.16.5-0ubuntu1 | amd64 | KDE window manager effects library
ii | wine-stable-amd64 | 5.0.0~eoan | amd64 | WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
```

**UPDATE #2**:

I have upgraded to 20.40 and to install in two different ways:

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable                                                                     4704  21:14:36    kubesail-alexey-anufriev/alexey-anufriev ⎈
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 4.0.4~focal)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And:

```
sudo apt install wine64 wine32                                                                                    100 ↵  4705  21:15:40    kubesail-alexey-anufriev/alexey-anufriev ⎈
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Still no luck.

**UPDATE 3**

```
$ sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{ab} libpcre3:i386{ab} 
  wine-stable{a} wine-stable-amd64{a} wine-stable-i386:i386{a} winehq-stable{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 52,3 MB of archives. After unpacking 466 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libodbc1 : Breaks: libodbc1:i386 (!= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
 libodbc1:i386 : Breaks: libodbc1 (!= 2.3.6-0.1build1) but 2.3.7 is installed
 libpcre3 : Breaks: libpcre3:i386 (!= 2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2:8.39-12build1 is to be installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Breaks: libpcre3 (!= 2:8.39-12build1) but 2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 winehq-stable : Conflicts: wine but 5.0-3ubuntu1 is installed
                 Conflicts: wine:i386 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - winehq-staging:i386 (5.9~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging:i386 (5.8~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging:i386 (5.7~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-stable:i386 (4.0.4~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel:i386 (5.9~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel:i386 (5.8~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel:i386 (5.7~focal), but it is not going to be installed
                            - wine (5.0-3ubuntu1), but 5.0-3ubuntu1 is installed
                            - wine (5.0-3ubuntu1), but 5.0-3ubuntu1 is installed
                            - wine-development (5.5-3ubuntu1), but it is not going to be installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                          
1)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 [Not Installed]                               
2)      libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
3)      libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                          
4)      libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
5)      libodbc1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
6)      libpcre3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
7)      wine-stable [Not Installed]                                                  
8)      wine-stable-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
9)      winehq-stable [Not Installed]                                                

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                   
10)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
11)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libodbc1:i386

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

```
$ apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable wine32 wine64

winehq-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.4~focal
  Version table:
     4.0.4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.4~focal
  Version table:
     4.0.4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
wine32:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
wine64:
  Installed: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources

Comment: sorry, but how this can help?

Comment: Please add output of the following commands to the question body (or upload to pastebin): `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable`, `dpkg -l | grep -i wine`.

Comment: @N0rbert, done, I have updated the question

Comment: Just a simple question. Did you forgot to run `sudo apt update`? Please share its complete output to pastebin too.

Comment: @N0rbert, run it probably a million times.

Comment: @N0rbert, anything you can suggest I still can dig into?

Comment: I do not have exact solution. The main concern is that your APT tried to remove essential packages. We can reinstall them by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt adduser coreutils libselinux1 dash dpkg debconf tar fdisk libmount1 findutils grep install-info gzip init systemd-sysv init-system-helpers  perl-base login libpam0g libpam-runtime libpam-modules mount util-linux sed sysvinit-utils`. And then try to fix Wine. If this a VM and you do not loose many workhours, consider to do full-reinstall of LTS version. Of wait for final release of 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @N0rbert, upgrade to 20.04 unfortunately did not help. You can see the output in the updated section of the question.

Comment: Does this help?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240184/can-not-install-wine-on-lubuntu-20-04/1240237#1240237

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable wine32 wine64` to the question.

Comment: @Ollie, tried your suggestion but it did not help, I have added aptitude output to the question (see UPDATE 3 section).

Comment: @N0rbert, added, see UPDATE 3 section

Comment: Try this It contains everything https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine/316029#316029

Comment: @AdupaVasista, already tried this, did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using modern Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - I would recommend to remove WineHQ repository and install Wine 5.0.3 [from *universe*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=wine):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies
```

Below I summarize steps done in the comments:

```
# remove obsolete PPA
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

# check real reason of the problem
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install wine32:i386
```

By last command we have determined that there are several locally (previously from some repository) installed packages. We need to replace them with versions from the official repositories:

```
sudo aptitude install libfaudio0=20.04-2 libodbc1=2.3.6-0.1build1 libpcre3=2:8.39-12build1
```

And finally install Wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine wine32
```

Comment: This way I can install win64 but not wine32. The following packages have unmet dependencies: wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed.

Comment: I can;t reproduce your problems on clean fully updated VM. Please check the output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable wine32 libwine:i386`, `dpkg -l | grep -i wine` again - upload it to pastebin.

Comment: done https://pastebin.com/r1wu84Kk

Comment: The GNOME PPA does not have packages for focal. Remove it with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` . Then run `sudo apt-get update` and retry Wine32 installation with `sudo apt-get install wine32` . If error persists please share the output of full `sudo apt-get update` to pastebin.

Comment: done - https://pastebin.com/EEeyv6L5

Comment: I can't understand why you are still facing the issues. Please switch to main server (`archive.ubuntu.com`), then run `sudo apt-get update` with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` .

Comment: which ones should I change?

Comment: Change all `de.archive.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com` using text editor or Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) - set *Download from* to *Main server*.

Comment: did that, still `wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Do you have all upgrades installed currently? Do you have `aptitude` installed?  If not install both `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` , `sudo apt-get install aptitude` , `sudo aptitude install wine32:i386` , `aptitude why-not wine32:i386` . And share the output of two latter commands.

Comment: done, https://pastebin.com/KLuDwbXS, I think there is something with `libodbc1:i386`

Comment: It seems I found the problem. You have faudio installed. Let's check from which source it, pcre and odbc was obtained by `apt-cache policy libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libpcre3 libpcre3:i386` - add to pastebin.

Comment: done https://pastebin.com/iR8fk8fX

Comment: OK, so you have to install some packages from official repositories with `sudo aptitude install libfaudio0=20.04-2 libodbc1=2.3.6-0.1build1 libpcre3=2:8.39-12build1` and then install wine32.

Comment: it worked, installation complete, thank you, @N0rbert!