# Unable to install wine stable because of "broken packages"

Tags: wine

As reported on the subject, I've failed installing the latest stable wine version because a broken package has accurred in my computer. Particularly, after typing

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

the following message have appeared

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 7.0.1~focal-1)
           Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 7.0.1~focal-1) but 4.0~bionic is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Acording with what I've found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448350/unable-to-install-wine-stable-because-of-broken-packages?noredirect=1#comment2528196_1448350), In what follows more details of what I did.

Here is my system

```
lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.2 Tina
Release:    19.2
Codename:   tina

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash containerd
  golang-docker-credential-helpers gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatomic1:i386 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libboost-signals1.65.1 libcap2:i386
  libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
  libedit2:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libelf1:i386
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libexif12:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgd3:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-common libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libicu60:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm10:i386 libllvm8:i386 libmpg123-0:i386
  libodbc1:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386 liborbit-2-0 liborc-0.4-0:i386
  libosmesa6:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsensors4:i386 libsndio6.1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
  libssl1.1:i386 libtheora0:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxpm4:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 lyx-common ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 pigz python-asn1crypto
  python-backports.ssl-match-hostname python-cached-property python-certifi
  python-cffi-backend python-cryptography python-docker python-dockerpty
  python-dockerpycreds python-docopt python-funcsigs python-functools32
  python-idna python-ipaddress python-jsonschema python-mock python-openssl
  python-pbr python-requests python-texttable python-urllib3 python-websocket
  python-yaml runc ubuntu-fan wine-stable wine-stable-amd64
  wine-stable-i386:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 465 not upgraded.
```

Here the system answer when I remove wine

```
$ sudo apt remove wine winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed
Package 'winehq-stable' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash containerd
  golang-docker-credential-helpers gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatomic1:i386 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libboost-signals1.65.1 libcap2:i386
  libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
  libedit2:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libelf1:i386
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libexif12:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgd3:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-common libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libicu60:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm10:i386 libllvm8:i386 libmpg123-0:i386
  libodbc1:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopus0:i386 liborbit-2-0 liborc-0.4-0:i386
  libosmesa6:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsensors4:i386 libsndio6.1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
  libssl1.1:i386 libtheora0:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxpm4:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 lyx-common ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 pigz python-asn1crypto
  python-backports.ssl-match-hostname python-cached-property python-certifi
  python-cffi-backend python-cryptography python-docker python-dockerpty
  python-dockerpycreds python-docopt python-funcsigs python-functools32
  python-idna python-ipaddress python-jsonschema python-mock python-openssl
  python-pbr python-requests python-texttable python-urllib3 python-websocket
  python-yaml runc ubuntu-fan wine-stable wine-stable-amd64
  wine-stable-i386:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 465 not upgraded.
```

Here the system answer when I try to install wine again

```
$ sudo apt install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 7.0.1~focal-1)
           Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 7.0.1~focal-1) but 4.0~bionic is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can you help me to properly understand what does it say and how can I fix it, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install wine on ubuntu 19.10/20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226845/cannot-install-wine-on-ubuntu-19-10-20-04)

Comment: unfortunatly not. My system stops here: sudo apt install wine-stable-i386. And it says sudo apt install wine-stable-i386

Comment: The problem is similar: You installed a version of Wine that is incompatible with your Mint system. The solution is to install a *different* version of wine that is compatible. Locating that Mint-compatible version is up to you.

Comment: I did what's written here https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-linux-mint-19.html , which is my system. But still the some message of broken packages

Comment: Not sure about Mint, but on Ubuntu it's usually a bad idea to follow directions on some random web page about how to install wine. Just use the tested, working version in the basic repos.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit is not enabled on your system.
Do:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update 
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install wine-stable
wineboot
```

or you can install winehq's wine:
For ubuntu 22.10:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/winehq-kinetic.sources
sudo apt update
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winehq-stable
```

for Ubuntu 22.04(Or Linux mint 21):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
sudo apt upgrade
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winehq-stable
```

Comment: libsane1 : Breaks: libsane1:i386 (!= 1.1.1+git20220801-focal0) but 1.1.1-5 is to be installed

Comment: @assayag.org try this: https://github.com/RishonDev/winehq-installer

Comment: still same error

Comment: Probably updating to a newer release will help. `sudo do-release-upgrade`