# Can't install a .exe with wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to play Ragnarok Online. I downloaded its launcher and wine too and I was trying to install it but this is coming up on my screen. What do I do? ! This is what I got when I used @Raffles 's method.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ wine start /unix NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64- 
AllOS-ENU.exe 
0040:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent 
assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ 0040:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 
00000000 1 00000000 0 stub
0040:fixme:clusapi:OpenCluster ((null)) stub!
0040:fixme:clusapi:ClusterOpenEnum (DEADBEEF, 4) stub!
0040:fixme:clusapi:ClusterEnum (DEADBEEF, 0, 0031F820, 0093D150, 261) 
stub!
0040:fixme:clusapi:ClusterCloseEnum (DEADBEEF) stub!
0040:fixme:clusapi:CloseCluster (DEADBEEF) stub!
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, 
hres=0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface 
{6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0048:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

[It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5nS8.png) After I click yes, it goes away and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

The message is saying that the game needs `.net` installed.

To make things much easier, you can use `playonlinux` to install the game.

Install `playonlinux` by `sudo apt install playonlinux`.

Then open the app and click "Install program". Add "Ragnarok" to the search field.

The game is supported. Follow the instructions. `playonlinux` should install all needed automatically.

Comment: "The Wine configuration in home/ubuntu/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/default is being updated, please wait" has been there for almost half an hour now. Should it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install .Net 4.5.2 this way, in a terminal :

`export WINEARCH=win64`

`winetricks vcrun2013 vcrun2015 corefonts`

`winetricks win7`

- Download .NET Framework 4.5.2 (offline version) and install it with the command:

`wine start /unix NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe`

-then run the  Ragnarok installer

Comment: Facing a problem, "An error was encountered, invalid handle"

Comment: During which step did it happen?

Comment: During the last step. I installed the .Net framework but the problem kept happening. Will now try again.

Comment: I've added an edit to the main question, its what I'm getting when I input the last step.

Comment: @Squadey I have to get back to you later today, meantime check out the WineHQ page for Ragnarok here >>> https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=928

They are talking about a 32 bit wine prefix however, so it might be out of date.

Comment: If the above steps fail to install .NET 4.5.2 then I would suspect that your Wine installation is faulty. The best way to reinstall Wine would be with Synaptic Package Manager. Otherwise take a look at this topic >>> https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine#316029