# How do you run a 32-bit Windows program on Ubuntu 20.04 using wine?

Tags: 20.04, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

In response to my previous off-topic question, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276654/how-do-you-install-wine-properly-on-ubuntu-20-10), I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a VM in Windows as I need to do some things with it. How do I configure wine properly to install a 32-bit program on 64-bit Ubuntu without configuration issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 32bit versions of wine and there are 64bit versions of wine.

Look in your WINEPREFIX/drive_c/ folder. There should be a **Program Files** folder.

If you see the **Program Files** ONLY and no ProgramFiles(x86) Then you are using 32bit wine.

If you see both then you are using 64bit wine.

Comment: but how do you install it? Is it wine, wine32, or both?

Comment: and I thought on Windows Program Files means 64-bit? Then why is it that the 32-bit version has that directory

Comment: The 64bit wine will run 32bit AND 64bit applications. CHeck this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Comment: so do I install wine or wine32? @darth_epoxy

Comment: Ok if YOUR machine is 64bit and running 64bit Ubuntu then the wine that you install would be 64bit also. To be sure that your wine also runs 32bit windoze applications type `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and hopefully no errors for you.